# Desktop computer is better, for running Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, laptop, memory, cpu, desktop

Good day,

Could you please help me with the computer hardware question?

I work on Excel spreadsheets. Data sets in the spreadsheets are big. When formulas are applied to the spreadsheets, it takes long to complete the computation (depends on the complexity of the formulas, sometimes a set of formula takes more than 1.5 hour to complete).

I am working on the laptop (2.5 GHz, 8G RAM). So I’m thinking if change to a desktop computer would help.

Thinking a desktop computer is the solution, when the budget is tight, which area shall I invest more? Do I need a faster processor/CPU, or a bigger RAM is better for Excel spreadsheets running?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me what CPU you have at the moment?

Comment: This isn't the kind of question that has a single definitive answer.  It depends on a lot of things.  If the spreadsheet is so big and complex that the computer can't hold everything it needs in memory, more RAM (or fewer concurrent apps), could make a huge difference.  If heavy duty calculations are what is taking the time, a more powerful CPU could make a difference.  Any desktop PC isn't necessarily more powerful than any laptop.  The only way to determine what will make a significant difference in your case is to try running the spreadsheet on different platforms and see.

Comment: @Dylan Rz, my laptop has Intel Core i7 5500U 2.4 GHz Processor.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for the comment. I ran the speadsheet on a new laptop (2.5 GHz, 8G RAM), and a old desktop (3.0 GHz, 4G RAM). the performance is about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details on the hardware, and you mentioning that the data sets are large, you would likely see the biggest benefits from:

1) SSD (Solid State Drive) if you don't already have one.  This drastically reduces read/write times to the disk, including swapping to the pagefile. If you don't know how to do it, a tech shop or Geek Squad should be able to mirror your old drive onto the new SSD.

2) More RAM.  Again, with large data sets, the more that can be loaded into memory, the less swapping to disk that is required.

If you do still opt to go with a new desktop, I still recommend an SSD and at least 16 GB of RAM (32GB would be better).

Comment: These things might help, or they could be a waste of money and not make a significant difference.  There's no way to make reliable recommendations.

Comment: @fixer1234, generally speaking, isn't a desktop (on bigger power consumption) faster than a laptop? and the same amount of investment/money can buy a faster desktop than laptop? thanks.

Comment: @MarkK, you already tried a desktop PC and found it didn't make much difference, although it wasn't a very controlled experiment.  You could buy a desktop computer and then find that the time isn't much different.  But if you have money burning a hole in your pocket and are going to buy a computer anyway, you will get more computing power for the dollar, and more expandability, with a desktop.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for the comment. I am going to buy a desktop.

Comment: @MarkK, that's your story and you're sticking to it.  We all know you're looking for an excuse to buy a new computer because you want one.  Admit it.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, desktop is more realiable, stronger, faster and cheaper. it's human's good friend. check today your Hello－Kitty coin bank to see if can buy one.

Comment: @fixer1234 Without all the details on the type of data (how large is large?) and formula that is being executed, of course you cant me 100% certain that it will improve performance drastically, but an SSD over a standard hard drive will improve seek/access times for all data on disk by a noticeable amount on any computer.  Even if you are running 10k rpm HDD, you will notice a huge improvement on disk access and boot times. Most off the shelf laptops also usually only come with 5400 rpm drives unless you bought high end.

Comment: @JeffHoerig, if the whole spreadsheet is RAM-resident, the storage device might not be accessed at all, so its speed would be irrelevant to run time in that case.